# Create polygon outline of raster

Tags: qgis, raster, feature-layer

I have several raster images with irregular shapes. I need to make a spatial analysis in the sense of "select all polygons that are within the raster." just like I can do with vectors. In QGIS, it seems to be not possible to do this with rasters as well, so at the moment, I am redrawing the raster outline in a new shapefile to do this analysis.

I could not find a more sophisticated solution to this better and faster, so I hope you can help me:

How can I create a polygon whose shape represents the shape of an overlaying raster image?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing some rasters?

Comment: I would consider zonal raster analysis. If the polygon does not contain any nodata pixel  then it is within a raster. You must mosaic the rasters together first. I would use gdalbuildvrt for that.

Comment: The "outline" of a raster is a rectangle. If you mean the non-NODATA portion, that can get tricky, and a screenshot would be very useful.

Comment: you could convert your raster to XYZ files and get that outline with convex/concave hull.

Answer (score 0):

Try the gdaltindex utility for this. You'll find it by searching for "Tile Index" in the Processing Toolbox (or simply use the command line)